# How to sort array list by specific character?

Tags: java

I need to sort arrayList by order of specific character, for example `C`. So if there is a word that starts with letter C it will be first, if it has a C in the middle it will be second and if it has C last, the word will be last.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

    str.add("doctor");
    str.add("basic");
    str.add("car");
}
```

Output:

**c**ar, do**c**tor, basi**c**

Comment: The problem is under-specified.  In which order will the three words "doctor", "document" and "docent" appear, and what is the rule that specifies the order?

Comment: Use a custom comparator that uses the `c`'s position in the string. But what what happens if more than one `c`?

Comment: It looks like you desire to sort the entriess depending upon the index position of char `C` in the entry. You use a comparator that is define how will it compare given 2 entries and pass or use that comparator. Or you may use a Key-Value binding with key as string and value as index of `C` in that string, then sort the Map per value

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom comparator for your needs, take a cue from this piece of code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        str.add("doctor");
        str.add("basic");
        str.add("car");
        char letter = 'c';
        // Compare method returns -1, 0, or 1 to say if it is less than, equal, or greater to the other.
        Comparator<String> customComparator = (str1, str2) -> {
            if (str1.indexOf(letter) < str2.indexOf(letter))
                return -1;
             if (str2.indexOf(letter) < str1.indexOf(letter))
               return 1;
            return 0; // To add other logic
        };

        Collections.sort(str, customComparator);
    }
```

In the code above a coarse logic is implemented based on your question, you would just need to complete the logic in the custom comparator to manage the specific cases.

Comment: Unfortunately that code fails with most characters. See [this example code run](https://ideone.com/owsQwa) at IdeOne.com. The `char` type is legacy, essentially broken. Use code point integers instead.